# How can I apply a texture to the transparent png? actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to apply texture to the transparent png(bitmap), but I don't want to include transparent areas. Texture will cover only non transparent side. My png is also 3D.
Pictures are shown below. Color transform working well to change non transparent side but I dont know how can I change texture.
It's code like that;

```
var ss:Sprite=new Sprite();
ss.graphics.beginBitmapFill(exampleModel);
ss.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
ss.graphics.endFill();

container.addChild(ss);
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works.

```
private function createHitArea(bitmapData:BitmapData, grainSize:uint=1):Sprite{
    var _hitarea:Sprite = new Sprite();
    _hitarea.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1.0);         
    for(var x:uint=0;x<bitmapData.width;x+=grainSize) {
        for(var y:uint=grainSize;y<bitmapData.height;y+=grainSize) {                    
            if(x<=bitmapData.width && y<=bitmapData.height && bitmapData.getPixel(x,y)!=0) {
                _hitarea.graphics.drawRect(x,y,grainSize,grainSize);                        
            }                   
        }
    }           
    _hitarea.graphics.endFill();                        
    return _hitarea;
}
```

source from: http://www.webverwirklichung.com/en/blog/programming/flex/creating-hitarea-png-image-transparent-alpha-regions-flex

Answer (score 1):

personally i think that this job/problem would be better dealt with the BitmapData class. 
E.g. Write an algorithm to cycle through all of the image pixels, use getPixel() to see if the pixel is transparent, and then use setPixel() to fill in the image pixel if applicable. 
Using the bitmapdata class would also allow for some flexibility, e.g. choosing which part of the image to use when 'filling' the target image. Hope this could help.